# R can't install devtools or git2r due to lack of zlib on macOS 10.12.3 and 10.12.5

Tags: r, macos, zlib, devtools

I am trying to install two packages in R (3.3.2): `devtools` and `git2r`. They are depending on the existence of `zlib`. This comes with macOS Sierra (10.12.3) and it's version 1.2.8 by default. 
When I'm trying to install these packages I get the error below.

I've been trying a lot of things.

- directly installing via CRAN in RStudio: no effect.
- trying to locate `zlib` on macOS: can't find `zlib`.
- installing via `R CMD INSTALL git2r`: no effect.

I notice someone has a similar issue posted on GitHub: https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues. There is no solution yet.

Does anyone here have an idea?

Thanks!

Sander

ERROR MESSAGE BELOW

> configure error in "/private/tmp/RtmpP6HZFx/R.INSTALLe73412909267/git2r"
>
> configure error
>
> ---
>
> The zlib library that is required to build git2r was not found.
>
> Please install:
>
> zlib1g-dev (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
>
> zlib-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
>
> and try again.
>
> If the zlib library is installed on your system but the git2r configuration is unable to find it, you can specify the include and lib path to zlib with:
>
> "R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-zlib-include=INCLUDE_PATH --with-zlib-lib=LIB_PATH' git2r"
>
> ---
>
> See "config.log" for more details
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package "git2r"
>
> *removing "/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/git2r"

UPDATE: the same issue persists on macOS X 10.12.5 in combination with R 3.4.0 - the latter I *need* for `DESeq2`.

Comment: You need to install Xcode and the command-line utilities in order for the header files to show up in /usr/include.

Comment: That's the thing: these are installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution...Mmm. Not *really*. I simply uninstalled R and all the packages, and than I reinstalled everything again. I installed `R` and `RStudio` via `homebrew`, following the instructions here: https://rud.is/b/2015/10/22/installing-r-on-os-x-100-homebrew-edition/.

Oddly enough: all issues disappeared.

UPDATE #1: this solution does not - obviously - work for the combination R 3.4.0 and macOS X 10.12.5. We need a solution for this issue.

UPDATE #2: I have discovered what I believe was the issue: a wrong path to the xcode command line tools.

`sudo xcode-select --reset` did the trick and now `xcode-select -p` points to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. And `which xcode-select` points to `/usr/bin/xcode-select`. Googling I discovered that it is not needed to install Xcode through the App Store as it states on http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html:

"On earlier versions of macOS, it was more difficult to install Xcode Command Line Tools. It required a huge download of the full Xcode package from the Mac App Store or registration as an Apple developer for a smaller Command Line Tools package. Mac OS X Mavericks made installation of Xcode Command Line Tools much simpler.".

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem. i have a note 8(samsung). just go to [GitHub](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#zlib) and install zlib from there.